React state Object loses content
Problem:
- I have a state variable (Object) that I fill through 2 async functions.
- My useEffect() is called when this variable changes. This happens twice (as expected).
- But each time I assign a value to a key, the other key-value is empty!
...Why?

State variable called "pageData":
interface DataState {
    marketData: any[]
    totalCash: number
}
const [pageData, setPageData] = useState<DataState>({
    marketData: [],
    totalCash: 0
});

There are 2 asyncronous functions loading data from the server:
setPageData({...pageData, totalCash: 821916.994425});

...and the other...
setPageData({...pageData, marketData: [{test: 1}, {test: 2}, {test: 3}]});

My useEffect event:
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('event useEffect pageData', pageData);
}, [pageData]);

...

When you want to update the state value based on previous value it is always better to use state updater pattern.
setPageData(prev => ({...prev, totalCash: 821916.994425}));

setPageData(prev => ({...pageData, marketData: [{test: 1}, {test: 2}, {test: 3}]}));

That way, the value of state will always be the latest one.
Although you have not shown where you call these state updates, i suspect this could be the problem.

Ah!! Indeed I was missing the "prev" injection. thanks
